# rEFInd doesn't show Kali installed on a usb drive

Tags: osx, kali-linux, usb-drive, refind

I have installed Kali on an USB from an old Macbook pro 2015, I had installed it in such way (so I thought?) as when plugged into any computer, the boot menu would show up the Kali.

Kali shows up fine on the Macbook pro 2015 where I installed it and it shows up fine when plugged in on any window machine.

However, I have a Macbook pro 2018 with rEFInd installed and it doesn't seems to detect the Kali partition ? The boot menu only shows the standard "osx" boot logo.

Is there a way I can either force rEFInd to boot into the Kali or fix somehow the usb drive so that it shows up on the boot menu of any computer ?

Comment: According to the `refind.conf` docs on macs this should be the default.  Edit your `refind.conf` to include `scanfor  internal,hdbios,external,biosexternal` to force looking for these and then leave a comment @Fabby